# Parse analytics not tracking custom events

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I was using Parse to track some custom events for my project. On the first version I had I was just using:

```
[PFAnalytics trackEvent: @"Some event string"];  // This works
```

But then I decided to put track more events, specially In-App purchases, so I created a few more with a dictionary like so:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{
              @"Item name" : itemName,
              @"Price" : priceString };

[PFAnalytics trackEvent:@"User Purchase" dimensions:dict];
```

But somehow even after shipping the second version this event doesn't show up on my dashboard, but the `@"Some event string"` event does. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

I've checked keys and values for the dimensions dictionary but everything appears to be Ok, And I've even tried to do a `"User Purchase"` event without dimensions, but it doesn't work either.

It seems that these code is so simple that something in my config inside Parse. But then I can't explain why does the first event kept working, can the `PFAnalytics` class have a bug?

**Update:**
It seems I was not familiar with the dashboard functionality and my events were being recorded. You have to go into "Custom Breakdown" in order to see your custom events. Now I can see my events.

Comment: Please post your update as an answer, you're allowed to answer your own questions, and even mark your own answer as correct.

Comment: I was going to do that, but it gave me a warning. Do you think it's a good idea?

Comment: Just word it and explain it as if someone else had asked the question so others will benefit from it. Answering your own questions is actually encouraged in the site guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **spaces** in events names.

For example change `"User Purchase"` to `"UserPurchase"`

[my answer to equal question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30562619/886703)