# Parse Analytics custom events do not appear

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, custom-event

I'm tracking custom events in Parse 1.7.2 in Swift with:

```
   let dimensions = ["category" : "politics"]     
   PFAnalytics.trackEventInBackground("Read", dimensions: dimensions, block: { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    })
```

and I've also tried

```
   let dimensions = ["category" : "politics"]     
   PFAnalytics.trackEventInBackground("Read", dimensions: dimensions, block: nil)
```

But my custom events do not appear in Analytics > Events > Analytics Requests > Custom Breakdown. I've done this: [Parse analytics custom event not registering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509376/parse-analytics-custom-event-not-registering) and this: [Parse analytics not tracking custom events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24448518/parse-analyitics-not-tracking-custom-events) and I've also read the Parse documentation and waited a few days to see if the data appears.

Parse does receive the data in Analytics > Explorer > Custom Events, but how can I see my custom events in the Events tab?

**UPDATE**

[Finally found a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24448518/parse-analyitics-not-tracking-custom-events)!

Comment: **SOLUTION** I've found an answer! [Parse analyitics not tracking custom events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24448518/parse-analyitics-not-tracking-custom-events)

Comment: What is the difference between Parse.com and PHPMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

To see your custom events in the Dashboard, you have to select "Custom Breakdown" in the "Events" section as shown in the image below:

[image]

The Custom Breakdown panel thereafter shows up where you can select your custom event and also turn on the dimensions you are interested in as shown below:

[image]

When you select your custom event and turn on the dimensions you are interested in, the analytics for your custom events is displayed and you have the option to save the breakdown for future use.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I've mentioned in my original question that I've already tried Analytics > Events > Analytics Requests > Custom Breakdown and my custom events still don't appear. The only filter it shows me is "Platform".