# parse analytics not showing event tab

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm new to Parse and I've just tried adding a basic event.the event tab under the analytic is not showing.
i have added custom event through my android app.after 10-15 hr still no event tab or event shown on dashboard of parse.
please help me out on this

Comment: Hi Ganesh, welcome to SO. Could you include the code that help you do what you say is not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse analytics not tracking custom events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24448518/parse-analytics-not-tracking-custom-events)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the analytics events

- in the **old** Parse.com dashboard:
  [image]
- in the **new** Parse.com dashboard:
  [image]

Comment: Thank you Manuel for your help i have sort out the issue